# Which Access Levels to use to make enum accessible only for that Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to import two Xcode Project in one. Now both the projects have an `enum BakerType` defined. This is creating a conflict.

Is there any way to restrict the scope of `enum` to that project only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **internal** access that enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that module.